# How to allow user to enter only 0 or 1?

Tags: asp.net

How to allow user to enter only 0 or 1 in the textbox.I am using C#.net. Textbox has maxlength is 1.I am want to add validation expression in regular expression.I don't want use javascript.

Comment: It's impossible without javascript. You could use a checkbox, though.

Comment: ValidationExpression=" /^[0-1]{1}$/" I use this in regular exression validator.But it promt 0 or 1 also.

Comment: are you sure it doesn't use javascript behind the scenes?

Comment: He might be doing this in C# server-side

Comment: @JanDvorak: in my opinion the question is  pretty clear, he don't want to use javascript to prevent that the users enetres something else than 0 or 1. But he wants to use a **validator** for this. A validator validates normally on client- _and_ on serverside. So the restriction is not that he cannot use js but he don't want to use js only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the question in the following way:

you don't want to use javascript only to prevent that the users enters something else than 0 or 1 but a **validator** which can be used on client- and on serverside.

I would use a [`RangeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `Type="Integer"` and   appropriate `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue`  instead.

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="Range1"
           ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
           MinimumValue="0"
           MaximumValue="1"
           Type="Integer"
           EnableClientScript="false"
           Text="The value must be from 0 to 1!"
           runat="server"/>
```

**Note**: If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds. Use a `RequiredFieldValidator` control to prevent the user from skipping an input control.

As other have mentioned, a `CheckBox` might be more appropriate for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve this in a textbox without using JavaScript. ASP.NET is a server-side language which means that it only works on the server-side of the client-server relationship. JavaScript is a client-side language meaning that it runs directly in the user's browser and works on the actual page that the user is viewing.

While you could write JS to actually prevent the user from typing anything in the box that is not "0" or "1", this will anger your users. You could also write client and server-side code which will validate the input and throw an error.

There is still a better way though which doesn't use JS which will meet your needs: use a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that in this case the checkbox is the best suited for the job. If you want to use a textbox, for future expandability maybe, then using javascript is the best suited.
If you absolutely must do it in C# you can use the following, but please consider using javascript for this as that is much faster.

```
int value;
bool isValidNumber = (Int32.TryParse(myTextBox.Text, out value) && (value == 0 || value == 1));
```